# React : How to render API response data in fromat of data: Array(i) to react front end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to retrieve `names of the books written by a particular author`, where `author name` provided through `get` request.

My API works fine and retrieves relevant data. In this scenario, I'm getting API response JSON for `more than one book`.

API response JSON :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5cf40d9d74df260aa460a74b",
        "name": "Oliver Twist",
        "author": "Charles Dickens",
        "yearOfPublication": "1839",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5cf4115b4b557126a02c6087",
        "name": "David Copperfield ",
        "author": "Charles Dickens",
        "yearOfPublication": "1850",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5cf412c54b557126a02c6088",
        "name": "A Christmas Carol ",
        "author": "Charles Dickens",
        "yearOfPublication": "1843",
        "__v": 0
]
```

I have tried using `const books = this.state.data.toString();` and access book names through `{books.name}`, but it doesn't output the book names. However, when I `console.log()`, *response.data* also outputs relevant data successfully as :

```
0: {_id: "5cf40d9d74df260aa460a74b", name: "Oliver Twist", author: "Charles Dickens", …}
1: {_id: "5cf4115b4b557126a02c6087", name: "David Copperfield ", author: "Charles Dickens", …}
2: {_id: "5cf412c54b557126a02c6088", name: "A Christmas Carol ", author: "Charles Dickens", …}
```

Can anyone suggest a suitable way to output these values to react front end too ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `.toString()` ? just map over `this.state.data`, i.e `this.data.map(books=> console.log(books.name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the .toString().

Since you have any array you need to specify which element you want or map over the array.

```js
console.log(this.state.data[0].name);

// or to log all names
this.state.data.map(item => console.log(item.name));
```